# options to export to csv

Tags: apex, webservices

We currently have a scheduled batch process that sends out a nightly email that uses a visualforce email template that exports and attaches 4 CSV files.

We are now wanting to create a new process that will export the data directly, rather than send the 4 attachments in an email.  The size of the attachments is unwieldy and clogging up the recipients email boxes.  So, we are looking to change the process.
Is it possible to create an Apex web service that can be called externally by a third party that could generate the 4 CSV files?  Basically, an on demand call to query, retrieve, export to CSV and deliver the response to the requestor?  Is this possible?

I don't believe writing an Apex batch process to export the data will work because it can't send the data to an ftp site to be picked up, correct?

I was looking into Jitterbit as an option.  Can that be scheduled to run an export nightly or weekly and 
then deliver the exported CSV files to a ftp site?  Some middleware tools are not allowed due to corporate policies, so I'm wondering if the web service option is viable?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using the free version of the Jitterbit Data Loader(found [here](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ZoVEAU)) for a couple years now (can't speak to the web service option though) and absolutely love it. I just tested querying SalesForce and writing to an FTP site and it worked perfectly and can be scheduled. There are a couple of limitations with the free version, like adding another field forces a rebuild of the query but you can modify the where clause,  also haven't found a way to send out a notification of failure. Here are a few screens shots from setting up the test:

[image: Query]

[image: FTP]

[image: Schedule]