# Apex code to Export Csv file to ftp server

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex

I have to write an apex batch scheduler to send `user` information `csv` to some `ftp server`. I am able to generate the csv file with user records but I don't know how to send this csv file to ftp server with using the code.

Do we have any api methods to send generated csv to the ftp server.. by providing the username and password?

```
public class UserInformation implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
    string[] Lines;     ///  all records

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        lines = new String[0];
        String query = 'SELECT Username,Email from USER';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, SObject[] scope) {
        // process
        for (Sobject record : scope) {
            String line = '';
            // header row
            if (lines.size() == 0) {
                line = 'UserName, Email';
                lines.add(line);
            } else {
                // build your csv line here
                line += '"' + record.get('UserName') + '"'
                        + ',' + '"' + record.get('Email') + '"';
                lines.add(line);

                system.debug('Line No >>> ' + line);
            }
        }  // end of for loop
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // this will send the CSV file as an attachment
        String finalResults = String.join(lines, '\n');
        lines = null; // Free temp memory to avoid heap errors
        blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(finalResults);

        // how do i send it to ftp server from here now?
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how to do it through code, but as an alternative you could use Jitterbit free DataLoader and schedule an export of a csv file to an ftp site.

Comment: ok thanks.. is that free? and can i add the scheduler in jitterbit also.. and isnt it possible through salesforce data loader?

Comment: Haven't used DataLoader in a long time so I'm not sure, but you can create a schedule in Jitterbit and yup it's free.

Comment: Take a look at this question/answer, I added screenshots of how to do it... http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56898/options-to-export-to-csv

Comment: Thanks alot! I think this is what i needed... Let me try!

Comment: Just curious...can't you schedule your CSV export into your corp folder and have a shell script put that file into FTP server ?..

Comment: @UnderDog actually I m new into salesforce and  I am looking for the ways to do that.. and how do i send export csv to corp folder?

Comment: In the command line form of Apex data loader I believe you can specify the target folder also

Comment: You can go through this...https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line

Comment: @JennyB I am able to schedule query and send to ftp server.. but now do we have to deploy it? and where it will be deploy to schedule automatically even my system is off... do we have to install jitterbit on server.. or it does automatically from their server.

Comment: Yes you need to deploy it and you should see it in the schedule. It is client side so you would want it on a computer that is always on. We just have it on a small win 8 vm on one of our servers.